# Is the ban on women in Mt. Omine legally enforced?

Tags: japan

[Mount Omine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%C5%8Cmine) in Japan is said to be off-limits to women.  However, it isn't clear (at least from a quick browse of English-language websites) whether the ban is legally enforced, or whether the mountain is on private property. [On google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mount+%C5%8Cmine/@34.2527763,135.9230464,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x60069509b9524433:0x66ef5bf4d3ee36d4!8m2!3d34.252778!4d135.940556!5m1!1e4) the mountain and the surrounding area is shaded in green, which usually indicates that it is some sort of national/state park, i.e. government-owned property.  If that's the case, I find it hard to believe that there would be a police-enforced ban on women, in a developed first-world country, in a place otherwise open to the public.  Does anyone have definitive information about the rules on Mt. Omine?

---

Note: Please *do not* answer with something like "It may be *legally* OK, but it would be deeply disrespectful, and you should respect their culture ...", etc. I understand that this question may be controversial, but my intention is not to start a debate on this topic.

Comment: According to https://www.scoopwhoop.com/PlacesWhere-Women-Are-Banned/ (#3 on that page) the prohibition is voluntary and that no trespassing charges are ever pressed

Comment: This would also suggest that it's private (religious) property